# Allowing login using multiple forms of ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I've created an ASP.net web page that allows the user to create an account. This site is purely for my own practice with the environment, but I have a question about the best way to handle logging in.

My site is more or less (eventually) going to be similar to Twitter.

When the user signs up for the site, they are required to put in a company ID number and a handle. In addition, they have an option of adding an email address, if so desired.

On my login page, I want the user to be able to login with any of those three options (email address, company ID, or handle).

The confusion that I'm running into: what if someone makes a handle that is the same as someone else's ID? How do I handle that?

Would the best option be to validate based off of the (salted and hashed) password if it matches more than one? I would guess no, but I'm not sure.

Now, I know that there are a lot of different options to alleviate this problem (require at least one letter in the user handle being the primary one that comes to mind, or as someone commented, adding a constraint to deny the creation if the ID already exists), but since this is just a mental exercise for me I figure I should learn something about it.

Comment: Could this be solved with database constraints to stop entries with the same name being added?

Comment: Sure, it could, but in my hypothetical I don't want to make that kind of restriction on allowed handles. I'll add it to my "possible solutions that I don't want to use" section in my question.

Comment: I guess to be more specific, the reason that I don't think your solution would work is because, if my ID is 123456, but someone else creates 123456 as a handle before I can make my account, that would mean I no longer had the option to make an account.

Comment: Let's say you allow that to occur. Two people with the same 'ID'. Now, they forget their password. You need to send them a reset password link. Which of those two people do you send the reset password email to?

Comment: The "Forget password" page would require a distinction between the handle vs. the ID, and would also require them to have an email address in the first place.

Comment: I should clarify, they're all being stored as separate fields in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Let users specify the type of credentials they are providing.**

Create a separate login form for each type of credentials: company ID, handle, e-mail address. When a user visits the site, you ask them to select the type of credentials they are providing. You could even remember this preference in the browser's storage.

When the form is posted, you know exactly what to validate. You don't have to worry about a handle being the same as a company ID. Store company ID, handle, and e-mail address as separate fields in the database with each user's account.

This is similar to sites which use federated authentication and give user's the option to sign in with Google or Facebook.

[image]

Comment: I like this solution a lot! I'll have to figure out how to make this kind of tabbed form on my page (curse you, CSS!) but I think that this is probably the way that I would go if I can't figure out some way to let them all use the same field.